# Need to access specific element from array column in spark dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have an array column with two elements in a Spark DataFrame, and I need to get the second element with specific pattern instead of a position id.

Input DataFrame:

```
+---+------------+----+
| id|    objectid|name|
+---+------------+----+
|100|[100, AB100]| ABC|
|200|[200, AB200]| CDE|
+---+------------+----+
```

DataFrame Schema:

```
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- objectid: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- name: string (nullable = true)
```

Expected output:

```
+---+--------+----+
| id|objectid|name|
+---+--------+----+
|100|   AB100| ABC|
|200|   AB200| CDE|
+---+--------+----+
```

Comment: Use filter on the column to find the matching value and then explode?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `withColumn` to update the `objectid` column by:

1. converting `objectid` into a `String` with a space   as the separator between the elements through the `concat_ws` method ([Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#concat_ws(sep:String,exprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Column)), and then
2. matching the desired `String` with a regular expression that extracts `String`s with start with 2 letters and end with 3 numbers through the `regexp_extract` method ([Scala docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html#regexp_extract(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,exp:String,groupIdx:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column))

I suppose you are using Scala, but you can understand the core idea behind the following command(s) and "translate" it to Python or Java if it happens you use one of those languages. `df` is the name of the DataFrame, `concat_ws` takes a separator and a column as arguments, and `regexp_extract` takes a column, a regular expression, and the regular expression's group ID to match within a `String` (you can learn more about the arguments at the documentation links above).

You can either do this with two `withColumn` commands:

```
df.withColumn("objectid", concat_ws(" ", col("objectid")))
          .withColumn("objectid", regexp_extract(col("objectid"), "[\\w]{2}[\\d]{3}", 0))
```

Or just one with `concat_ws` nested inside `regexp_extract`:

```
df.withColumn("objectid", regexp_extract(concat_ws(" ", col("objectid")), "[\\w]{2}[\\d]{3}", 0))
```

Given output:

```
+---+--------+----+
| id|objectid|name|
+---+--------+----+
|100|   AB100| ABC|
|200|   AB200| CDE|
+---+--------+----+
```